Workshop scenario Palantir ERROR == ActionsSubmissionRuntimeError
after creating the scenario
created new object L1 in scenario using form
and once object is created in same scenario created the sublevel object L2 as taking the reference L1
and save the scenario in object table it show the data
but now i want to push this changes to main object it give the error
ActionsSubmissionRuntimeError
try created l1 object and push to main object and after that created the l2 object using reference of l1 object and then deployed to prod it work but i want the above functionality
